# Use open_memstream with c99

Tags: c, posix, c99

I am trying to use the `open_memstream` function in my C code. However I cannot seem to compile it. Minimal working example as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *buf;
    size_t sz;

    FILE *stream = open_memstream(&buf, &sz);
    putc('A', stream);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

And I also use the following command to compile it:

`gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c`

After some research, I found that I need to define a macro before I include `stdio.h`. However the following example code was to no avail.

```
#define __USE_POSIX
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <stdio.h>
```

The following compiler warnings are thrown; I assume the second warning is because of the first one.

```
test.c:7:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘open_memstream’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
FILE *stream = open_memstream(&buf, &sz);
             ^
test.c:7:17: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: Wrong macros. Never define those. Read `man open_memstream`.

Comment: Additionally, I see no question. Whatever it is you've confused yourself about those warnings (which aren't errors, btw), we can't read your mind. You need to tell us what part of them confuses you, so that we can help correct that confusion.

Comment: @Sebivor "which aren't errors" Please don't say this aloud, someone could get an impression that you don't know they are fatal.

Comment: @n.m. "they are fatal" is invalid for anything which is implementation-defined, because they might not be on some systems. Do you have any conclusive sources to back up that statement?

Comment: @Sebivor "Warnings" do not exist in the standard. The standard talks about diagnostics. I am not talking about the standard. I am talking about these specific warnings from this specific implementation.

Comment: @n.m. Which specific implementation is that? The implementation-defined aspects I'm referring to are the identifiers, of course. If they're documented by the implementation, then that's the conclusive documentation you'd want to use.

Comment: @Sebivor It's gcc. I have no idea why it claasifies these as warnings, especially the second one.

Comment: @n.m. It probably explains why in the documentation for `-Wimplicit-function-declaration`.

Comment: @Sabivor no I could not find any rationale in the documentation. IMO the first warning should be enabled by default in pre-c99 modes and be treated as an error by default in c99 and later, but what do I know. The second one should be an error always.

Comment: @n.m. Nobody has systematically re-examined the priorities of GCC's diagnostics in many years.  The defaults _were_ appropriate for the ecosystem I remember from the mid-1990s, where there was lots and lots of pre-C89 code floating around and people needed it to keep working.

Comment: @zwol even if you prioritize keeping old software afloat over writing new software, why keep these defaults for software that is obviously new (i.e. -std=c99 and up)?

Comment: @n.m. In an attempt to keep the command-line switches as orthogonal as possible, `-std=cXX` doesn't do anything that `-pedantic` would do.  Again, this is all design decisions from the 1990s or earlier that nobody has reexamined since.  (It's also important to keep in mind that there's very little product management going on in most open source projects.)

Comment: @zwol If I understand correctly, you've provided a rationale, which is that the "status quo" was maintained and thus the rationale is out of sync with the standard. Is this code likely to fail to compile on *any* system nowadays, if you were to compile using, say, `gcc -c -std=c99 test.c` (in order to cease compilation prior to the obviously fatal linker error which occurs at a later stage, which I think n.m. might have been referring to earlier when he said these warnings are fatal)?

Comment: @Sebivor I'm not sure I understand the question.  I can reproduce the warnings reported by Bert on my computer, with GCC 7 and GNU libc 2.25.  `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror` will make both warnings into errors (and specific warning classes can be turned into errors with e.g. `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`) but that's not done by any `-std=` switch nor do I think it _should_ be done by any `-std=` switch.

Comment: @Sebivor If I were still involved in GCC development, I might try to find time to reexamine all the cases where there's either an allowance for pre-C89 code or an on-by-default extension, and disable them _by default_ when they are no longer useful to modern code, but I think any change to the division of labor between `-std` and the warnings options risks breaking an unbounded number of existing build scripts and is therefore not practical.

Comment: @zwol What I'm getting at is the error that (I'm guessing) will follow, as the linker steps into action and fails to resolve the symbol. That indicates that if anything, the *first* warning is what should be an error, not the second, but I digress. What I'm interested in proving is that this *compiles*, as a distinct stage from *linking* as once the object code is produced, the C standard isn't so much in the picture any more. So... do you know of any `gcc` implementations which will fail at the *compilation* stage rather than just giving warnings up until the *linking* stage occurs?

Comment: @Sebivor Well, as it happens, Bert's program _does_ link just fine on my computer (and should on any other computer that is fully compliant with POSIX.1-2008).  But the direct answer to your question is no.  No existing version of GCC will issue an error, rather than a warning, for this code, unless you give `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` or an option that implies that one (such as `-pedantic-errors`, but not any of the `-std` options). I believe this is also the case for clang.

Comment: @zwol ... well, colour me ... any colour but ghostly heh, I'm that already. I suppose that makes sense, as you don't need to explicitly link to the POSIX library.

Answer (score 7):

The `__USE_*` macros are internal to glibc's headers, and defining them yourself does not work.  You should instead do one of the following:

- Compile your program with `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c99` and don't define any special macros.  This is the easiest change.  Conveniently, `-std=gnu11` is the default with newer versions of GCC.
- If you have some concrete reason to want to select an old, strict conformance mode, but also you want POSIX extensions to C, then you can use the *documented* POSIX feature selection macros:

  ```
  #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
  ```

  or

  ```
  #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
  ```

  These must be defined before including *any* standard headers.  The difference is that `_XOPEN_SOURCE` requests an additional set of features (the "XSI" functions).  See the [Feature Test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) section of the glibc manual for more detail.

  Note that if you need to request strict conformance mode from the *library*, using a `-std=cXX` option, then you almost certainly also want to use the `-Wall` and `-Wpedantic` options to enable strict conformance checking for the *language*.  (You should use at least `-Wall` even if you *don't* need strict conformance checking.)